Predict the nature of a dipole in a electrically neutral block in the presence of an electric field
Lets say I have 2 point charges on either side of the y axis, each being equidistant from the origin as shown.

Now I place a electrically neutral block on the x axis as shown.

Now a dipole is generated in the block. It could be any of these :

or

or

Is there any way to predict which of these would be correct or are all of these correct under different circumstances?

Of course! If the charges are both positive, then the electric field will go to the right in the axis of the neutral object, and so the negative charges will come closer to the positive ones ($Q$), whilst the positive charges will move to the right of the object (image 2), and while the object will still be neutral (since charge is conserved), it will now be polarized and acting as a dipole at sufficiently large distances. The opposite charge distribution holds when the charges are negative (image 1). If one of the charges is positive and the other one is negative, then ther will be no electric field in the object's axis, provided that it's half way between both charges. I invite you to have a look at Griffiths' Introduction to Electrodynamics, 4th Edition, page 167 ("induced dipoles"), chiefly at the concept of the electric displacement vector ($\vec D$).
Note: in the last case, where the charges have opposite values, there will be no electric field just in the X axis. If the positive and negative charge had different values, or if the object wasn't a one-dimensional rod (so it fits in the X axis), then it would be subject to electric fields, but the problem could easily be solved analytically, since the electric field generated by two arbitrary charges is simple to calculate using Coulomb's law and superposition

Of course they can all be correct under different circumstances, but you already pointed out the circumstances in your drawing.
In particular, you write that the neutral block is on the $x$-axis as shown, meaning that it is on the positive $x$-axis. And then there is of course no doubt about the induced charges, they must be as in the second case in the list.
If we do not keep strictly to the wording of the question, but instead consider a block at $any$ position on the $x$-axis, then we can also have the first case of the list (if the block is on the negative $x$-axis). But there doesn't seem to be any room for interpretations that would lead to the third listed alternative for the induced charges.
